# Can an "Editor" in a folder delete files within that folder?

Tags: google-drive

I created a folder in Google Drive, and I can share that folder with other users. I can select one of these permissions when sharing:

- Viewer
- Commenter
- Editor (Organise, add and edit files)

My question is concerning the "Editor" permission. Can someone with the Editor permission delete files in that Google Drive, even ones that they don't own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editors in a shared folder in Google Drive can do these things:

- **They can move these files**, even out of the shared folder. In this case, the owner won't see the file in its location, but can still access it by finding it with the search feature, or by clicking a link that points to it. The owner remains the owner of the file.
- **They can add new files** to the shared folder. New files that they own will remain owned by that user, even if the shared folder is owned by somebody else.
- **They automatically become "Editors"** of files in that shared folder, and can edit that file as you would expect. There is always the version history of Google documents if you need to revert someone's changes.
- **The "Move to bin" menu item does *not* appear** for Editors of the shared folder.

All new files in the shared folder will automatically inherit the permissions of the shared folder. However, it is possible to remove a user from a particular file, in which case, the file will simply not appear when that user views the shared directory. I don't recommend this, as I think it would cause confusion.

If you are using a shared folder for your team, you might want to **consider a [shared drive](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310351?hl=en) instead**. Files in a shared drive are owned by that drive, if you like, rather than by one user in particular.

If you want to add files to a shared folder but don't want all the users who have "Editor" access to folder to also have "Editor" access to the file, this is what you can do: **you can create a shortcut** to the file and place the shortcut in the shared folder.

Comment: Please remember that you can also [accept your own answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)